# Como reaproveitar menus HTML em outras paginas

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, front-end

Sou novato no front-end e gostaria de saber como posso escrever uma vez o menu e reaproveitar nas outras paginas? 
Já li alguns posts mas não consegui implementar no meu codigo.

Exemplo;
Tenho um menu da pagina principal e quero reaproveitar em todas as outras paginas desse mesmo site.

Comment: Recomendo fazer seu menu em um html separado e depois onde for usar importe ele

Comment: @user3110946 pelo menos fique online quando te responderem

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o conceito de [oocss](http://oocss.org/), que nada mais é que criar snippets de css modularizados, por exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/Lav1xpha/

```
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

    .button:focus, 
    .button:active,
    .button:hover {
      outline: 0;
      color: #fff;

}

.button-danger {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  color: #fff;
}

.button-danger:hover {
  background-color: #c0392b;
}
```

Aqui foi criado um exemplo bem simples, mas que demonstra um componente que você pode inclui-lo em diversas páginas quantas vezes quiser. e se você precisar criar um botão personalizado, basta criar apenas uma nova classe que sobrescreve a aparência desse botão, mas sem prejudicar os demais, obviamente, quando se usa essa abordagem, você jamais sobrescreve as classes principais, se não compromete todo o seu trabalho.

Indico ler alguns excelentes livros sobre esse assunto, e a respeito de nomenclaturas de classe css que facilitam essa abordagem de css modularizado:

[BEM](http://getbem.com/introduction/) - [Artigo](http://tableless.com.br/bem-um-novo-metodo-para-seu-css/), [outro artigo](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/pt/articles/an-introduction-to-the-bem-methodology--cms-19403).
[SMACSS](https://smacss.com/) - [Artigo](http://tableless.com.br/oocss-smacss-bem-dry-css-afinal-como-escrever-css/).
[ITCSS](http://itcss.io/) - [Slide](https://speakerdeck.com/dafed/managing-css-projects-with-itcss).

Comment: Obrigado, vou ler e vou aplicar no meu código.